# Is it ok to use gson for persisted data storage in android

Tags: android, json, database, gson, persistence

I have a deeply nested json which i'm using in my app

```
Playlist
 - ArrayList<Music>
            - more nested fields
 - name
 - etc..
```

When modifying any field, I convert whole object to json with

```
new Gson().toJson(obj);
```

and save it to file

Then read the whole file again, parse the json with GSON to get a value when required,
I perform operations like
reading track info, saving lastPosition, search track by name

I've written manual functions for this as query approach is not possible and not needed too

I dont want to use sqlite because data is nested and i dont wish to deal with relations
and Nosql libraries are huge in size ( Realm 12 mb)  which i want to avoid

But I feel my lightweight solution is not optimised

I also feel data might be currupted if toJson() output to file is written by multiple threads, how can i avoid this as much as possible ?

Is there any better lightweight and more optimised approach available for this use case?

Paper db is not suitable as i already have gson annotations to my classes as i'm using them in apis with retrofit

Comment: Why not simply use SQLite? Having no wish to "deal with relations" sounds like an excuse. When using SQLite, you have at least: concurrency support, ACID, query what you want not fetching all data into memory (what if your JSON grows many MBs?) even if now it is not needed, update only one field like `lastPosition` in case of necessity with an extremely simple and short `UPDATE` statement, kind of support for circular references.

Comment: @fluffy The data is primilarily json-like and server as priary source and using sqlite introduces more code dealing with flattening the json,etc, I want the data to remain in json like structure

Comment: Well, nothing is free: either use SQLite and all of its advantages paying for the flattening code, or use NoSQL libraries paying for their size, or use Gson with file system/shared preferences persistence paying for possible performance penalties (in case your data grows enough).

Comment: Considering the file will never grow above 100kb (and even if it does, i can do some improvements like saving different root keys in different files) maybe gson with file is best solution right now, I wonder why nobody faced such issue before. Still the question is open for optimizations

Comment: Just curious: did you probably find a solution?

Comment: using gson approach..